# Collection mutation in foreach upon exiting loop: is it an acceptable pattern?

Tags: c#, exception, collections, foreach, mutation

It's well known that the mutation of a collection within an iteration loop is not allowed. The runtime will throw an exception when, for instance, an item is removed.

However, today I was surprised to notice that there's no exception if the mutating operation is followed by any exit-loop statement. That is, the loop ends.

```
//this won't throw!
var coll = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
foreach (var item in coll)
{
    coll.RemoveAt(1);
    break;
}
```

I watched at the framework code, and it's pretty clear that the exception is thrown only when the iterator will moved forward.

My question is: the above "pattern" could be considered an acceptable practice, or is there any sneaky problem on using it?

Comment: +1... I assume you sample is not real code - consider adding comment like "this useless code just demonstrates the behavior...." to avoid "you can do that better comments".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: you're absolutely right. The snippet is just a minimal piece of working code, whereas the "RemoveAt" is just a mutating method. The problem is *NOT* whether an item can be removed, but the collection can be mutated without any exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you gave, and to answer the question "Is it good practice/acceptable to modify a collection during enumeration if you break after the change", it is fine to do this, **as long as you are aware of the side-effects**.

The primary side effect, and why I would not recommend doing this in the general case, is that the rest of your foreach loop doesn't execute. I would consider that a problem in almost every instance of a foreach that I have used.

In most (if not all) instances where you could get away with this, a simple if check would suffice (as Servy has in his answer), so you may want to look at what other options you have available if you find yourself writing this kind of code a lot.

The most common general solution is to add to a "kill" list, and then remove after your iteration:

```
List<int> killList = new List<int>();
foreach (int i in coll)
{
   if (i < 0)
      killList.Add(i);

    ...
}

foreach (int i in killList)
    coll.Remove(i);
```

There are various ways to make this code shorter, but this is the most explicit way of doing it.

You can also iterate backwards, which won't cause the exception to be thrown. This is a neat workaround, but you may want to add a comment explaining why you are iterating backwards.

Comment: +0: Not sure why you consider `break` a problem - "find first item that satisfy X" should not finish iteration of the collection...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I completely agree, if that was the intended use case. I interpreted the question as "Is this a good idea in general?", which I would say "No" to. I thought the provided code sample was just an example, one which illustrates a valid use case for `break` but not a very generalized one.

Comment: But I don't see "no, this is bad idea because ..." in your answer. Like "it is bad idea precisely because you need to ask this question - every future reader of the code will be contused and try to fix the mutation of the list inside `foreach` even if code works perfectly".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, thank you for your feedback. I have tried to make my opening statement more clear, do you agree that it is better? Thanks again.

Comment: Change made your intention clear, but I don't think change addressed the fact that you don't have direct answer to "is it ok to mutate collection in foreach if you `break` after the change".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Third times a charm :), Thank you again for helping me improve my answer.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: your example is right what I'd write. The "strange pattern" was taken by a third-party software, and when I watched at it I was sure on an exception. My suspect is the guy wrote it used kinda pattern for a bit of laziness (or C++ fashion, which I personally HATE)!

Comment: @MarioVernari, Probably. Using break and other control-flow statements  should be done with care anyways (as you say, can be a sign of a lazy programmer). Hopefully my answer was useful to you!

Answer (score 2):

So your example can be relied on to work, for starters.  Mutating a collection while iterating fails when you go to ask for the next item.  Since this provably never asks for another item after it mutates the list, we know that won't happen.  Of course, the fact that it works doesn't mean that it's clear, or that it's a good idea to use it.

What this is trying to do is remove the second item *if there is an item to remove*.  It is designed to not break when trying to remove an item from a collection without two items.  This is not a well designed way of doing that though; it's confusing to the readers and doesn't effectively convey its intentions.  A much clearer method of accomplishing the same goal is something like the following:

```
if(coll.Count > 1)
    coll.RemoveAt(1);
```

In the more general case, such a `Remove` in a foreach can only ever be used to remove *one* item, so for those cases you're better off transforming the `forech` into an `if` that validates that there is an item to remove (if needed, as it is here), and then a call to remove that *single* item (which may involve a query to find the item to remove, instead of using a hard coded index).

Comment: +1. I believe sample in the question is just that - the smallest piece of code that demonstrates the behavior. I'd try to word second half of the answer to be less referring to sample, but highlight find and remove suggestion...